Next.Js middleware cause issues with images and tailwind
middleware prevent tailwind from running and also make issue with images.
I guess its something with the matcher Regex.
Images are inside public/images (outside src)
favicon are inside puublic/favicon (outside src)
When connected (isLoggedIn) it works fine. when not connected it crashes images & tailwind CSS
The middleware looks like this:
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";

const middleware = (req: NextRequest) => {
  const isLoggedIn = cookies().get("auth-token")?.value;
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;
  if (
    !isLoggedIn &&
    pathname !== "/signin" &&
    pathname !== "/signup" &&
    pathname !== "/signin-google" &&
    pathname !== "/contact-us" &&
    pathname !== "/" &&
    !pathname.includes("forgotpassword")
  )
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/signin", req.url));
  else if (isLoggedIn && (pathname === "/signin" || pathname === "/signup"))
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/trainees", req.url));
};

const config = { matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'] }


export { config };
export default middleware;

